# supporting deep-linking with location regex and try_files, can't redirect to foo/local/ to foo/index.html

Tags: regex, nginx

I have a number of drop in GUIs that all under the general TTP subdomain and all allow deep-linking.  Specifically the URL /TTP/*app*/*site*/ should load GUI named *app* with *site*'s statistics.  with /ttp/*app* loading the same GUI with the default site.

This should work by redirecting both /ttp/*app* and /ttp/*app*/*site*/ requests to the /usr/share/html/ttp/*app*/index.html page, that page will parse the remaining url and figure out which backed to hit if *site* is provided.

Currently I have something like this in my conf file (I'm utilizing the nested location for other things not included here):

```
location /ttp {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/ttp/;
    location ~ ^/foo/ {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /foo/index.html;
    }
    location ~ ^/bar/ {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /bar/index.html;
    }
    ... (one for each app)
}
```

This works, but is redundant.  I'm trying to consolidate this with a regex which will cover all apps with a single location.  I've tried a few variants, original having issue with greedy regex grabbing all /*app*/*site*/ instead of just /*app*/.  My best attempt with non-greedy regex being

```
location /ttp {
    index index.html
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/ttp/

    location ~ ^/((?U).*)/ {
        try_files $uri /$1/index.html;
    }
}
```

this give me an error about rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting ti "/ttp/index.html"  Which seems to imply it's not greedy enough and is completely ignoring *app* with $1 being a null string.

Is there some clean way to do this, with regex or some directive I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Your example is flawed - I presume you over simplified it and we are missing the part that removes the `/ttp` prefix after it enters the outer `location` block.

You have a URI structure `/ttp/foo/xxx` and you would like the default action to be `/ttp/foo/index.html` where `foo` is the name of an app.

You can use non-greedy regular expression, but you may find the `[^/]` character class easier to use for matching individual path elements in the URI.

If the final element of a `try_files` statement needs a rewrite, use a named location. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

For example:

```
location /ttp {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^(/ttp/[^/]+)/ $1/index.html last;
    return 404;
}
```

Any URI of the form `/ttp/foo/xxx` that takes the default action, will re-enter the `location /ttp` block with the URI as `/ttp/foo/index.html`. The `root` parameter is prefixed to the URI to form the local path.